# How can I pull all modules in IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE project at once?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, multi-module

I have a multi-module project in IntelliJ. Each of the modules is stored in a separate git repository.

I have already set them up, so I marked each of them as VCS root in IntelliJ.

Am I able to pull all of them at once using IDE, or should I use command line tool? Currently I'm pulling them one by one:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To pull from all repositories at once, use VCS - Update project (`Ctrl/Cmd+T`)

The screenshot shows checkout command though.
If branches name in all repositories are the same, you should enable Synchronous branch control in Settings - Version control - Git, and you will be able to checkout all branches at once from the bottom part of the Branches pop-up

Comment: what if branches names are different ?

Comment: Update projects updates from the tracked branch. It does not matter how it is called, it just needs to be properly set in git config